# Create an app from responsive site that uses ajax calls that return both html and javascript - easiest way?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm looking for the easiest and most efficient way to create a mobile app from my website that is already fully responsive.

I have a page that contains 5 different ajax calls. Each ajax call returns both html and javascript which is created by a PHP script. All JavaScript that is is not user dependent is in a separate file. There is also a separate file for all css.

I think converting the code (using phonegap) will be very difficult because of the ajax calls. Preferably I would like to have an app that installs an icon on someone's phone and that just opens my website in a browser (without showing anything of that browser).

My question: What is the easiest way to create an app for android and ios?

Comment: That app will not pass review in Apples Appstore. (See submission guidelines)

Answer (score 1):

Webview? If you are looking to build an app that just opens your webpage and does not show that its opened AOSP browser or any other browser for that matter then just use webview. It would open like any other activity in your app but the content (depending on how big you want the webview) will just be your site. I did a very similar thing in my android app and here is the code.

Java Class:

> public class website extends Activity {
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_website);
>
>     String url = "http://www.YourWebsiteHere.co.uk";
>     WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webViewSite);
>     view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
>     view.loadUrl(url);
> }
> ```

XML File:

> ```
> <WebView
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:id="@+id/webViewSite"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentStart="true" /> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html